# Is it possible to extend Nebular's NbContextMenu?

Tags: angular, nebular

I'm trying to extend Nebular's NbContextMenuDirective to allow for asynchronous item retrieval.  I suppose the first question should be: is there an easier way to accomplish that?  If not, is there something missing in my attempt?

```
import { Directive, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { NbContextMenuDirective, NbMenuItem } from '@nebular/theme';

@Directive({ selector: '[appMenu]', exportAs: 'appMenu' })
export class MenuDirective extends NbContextMenuDirective {
  @Input('appMenu') loader?: () => Promise<Array<NbMenuItem>>;
  private _loaded = false;

  override show() {
    if (!this._loaded) {
      this.loader!.then(i => {
          this.items = i;
          this.loaded = true;
          this.show();
        });
    }
    else {
      super.show();
    }
  }
}
```

When clicking on the menu button, I'm getting this error in the console (and no menu displayed):

> re.mjs:8400 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'forEach')
> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'forEach')
> at NbMenuInternalService.prepareItems (nebular-theme.mjs:9532:15)
> at NbMenuComponent.ngOnInit (nebular-theme.mjs:10126:34)